# Memtest86+ showed errors before, now it doesn't ? what could this mean?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, memtest86+

I have 6 computers that are very similar in their hardware, they all have the `Intel DH61WW` motherboard, with i5 CPUs and 4GB RAM, all of these computers had the 32 bit version of Windows before, so I installed the 64 bit version and all the drivers from the Intel website and everything that I need on 1 computer and then I used [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to clone the hard drive image to all the others, we started experiencing Blue screen errors on 3 of these computers, I used [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to check the dumps, most of them were `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` errors pointing to `ntoskernel.exe`, the other errors were:

- `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA` (ntoskernel.exe)
- `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION` (ntoskernel.exe)
- `NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM` (Ntfs.sys)

These blue screen errors happen randomly, so when I started to get these errors a lot I ran a live USB version of [Memtest86+](http://memtest.org/) version 4.20 I got 4000+ errors from the first seconds on 1 computer and on the other 100+ errors, now if I try to run the same test again I don't get any errors, that's what's confusing me, is this normal with memtest ? or could this be another problem like another hardware issue or maybe a software issue ?

Comment: What has changed between the tests? Temperature? Humidity? Power supply? BIOS settings? Memtest86+ parameters? Perhaps, you should run a `chkdsk` disk check to rule-out filesystem/disk problems. Memtest86+ can take a long while to discover certain errors, but errors found during "the first seconds" should be easy to reproduce.

Comment: @AxelKemper Actually nothing has changed, but I remember that only after getting successive blue screen errors and then testing immediately I get the errors ? So when it happens again I'll run the test.

Answer (score 2):

I believe RAM errors may occur randomly depending on various factors like temperature and voltage variations. I suggest you try another computer stability test like Prime95, which really stresses the computer and reveals weaknesses in stability.
http://download.cnet.com/Prime95-64-bit/3000-2053_4-75869492.html
when you run it go to options / stress test